# updating Bokeh scatter plots data source with ipython widgets

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, ipywidgets

I am using an ipython widget to filter a pandas dataframe, and update the data source of some Bokeh scatter plots accordingly.

The code runs properly and there is no error, and still, changing filtering parameter values with the widget has not effect.

Can anyone tell me where the problem is? Thanks!

```
TOOLS = "box_select,lasso_select,help,hover"

source = ColumnDataSource(data=frame[['A',
                                   'B',
                                   'C'
                                  ]])

left = figure(tools=TOOLS,
          plot_width=300,
          plot_height=300)
left.circle('A', 'C', source=source, size=10)

right = figure(tools=TOOLS,
           plot_width=300,
           plot_height=300,
           title='A',
           x_axis_label = "B",
           y_axis_label = "C")
right.circle('B', 'C', source=source, size=10)

p = gridplot([[left, right]])

def update(tension):
    df = frame[frame['D']==tension]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=df[['A',
                                   'B',
                                   'C'
                                  ]])

left.circle('A', 'C', source=source, size=10)
right.circle('B', 'C', source=source, size=10)
p = gridplot([[left, right]])
print(df.shape, tension)
push_notebook()

show(p, notebook_handle=True)

interact(update, tension=frame.D.unique())
```

Selecting a value with the widget does change the value of "tension" and update the "df" dataframe, but has not impact on the plot.

Comment: Provide sample data for frame. @Clement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in update function. Check this code this will work. This produces warning for `D` column but you can ignore them.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import show,push_notebook,output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource,gridplot,figure

from ipywidgets import interact

frame = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],'B':[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],'C':[4,3,5,7,9,34,5,6,8,6],
                      'D':['Type A','Type B','Type C','Type A','Type B','Type C','Type A','Type B','Type C','Type A']})
output_notebook()

TOOLS = "box_select,lasso_select,help,hover"

source = ColumnDataSource(data=frame)

left_gp = figure(tools=TOOLS,plot_width=300, plot_height=300,x_axis_label = "A",y_axis_label = "C")
left = left_gp.circle('A', 'C', source=source, size=10)

right_gp = figure(tools=TOOLS, plot_width=300,plot_height=300,x_axis_label = "B",y_axis_label = "C")
right = right_gp.circle('B', 'C', source=source, size=10)

def update(tension):

    left.data_source.data['A'] = frame[frame['D']==tension]['A']
    left.data_source.data['C'] = frame[frame['D']==tension]['C']

    right.data_source.data['B'] = frame[frame['D']==tension]['B']
    right.data_source.data['C'] = frame[frame['D']==tension]['C']


    push_notebook()
p = gridplot([[left_gp, right_gp]])
show(p, notebook_handle=True)
interact(update, tension=frame.D.unique())
```

Please check the [official example](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/notebook.html#jupyter-interactors) in Bokeh doucuments.
Output look like this for that  example.[image]